# Sencha Touch - iframe scrolling in iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, iframe, sencha-touch

In one of my views, I have an Ext.Component that shows an iframe. 
It is defined like this:

Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView', 
    extend: 'Ext.Component',

```
alias: 'widget.myview',
id: 'myView',

config: {
    style: '-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; height: 100%; overflow: auto;',
    href: false
},

template: [
    {
        reference: 'iframeElement',
        tag: 'iframe',
        style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%; border: 0;'
    }
],

updateHref: function(href){
    this.iframeElement.set({ src: href });
}
```

});

When I render the component, I load the iframe content using updateHref('http://');

The problem is, on iPhone, when I scroll the iframe content down and the scrolling is ended, 
the document is scrolled back up automatically to the beginning.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a workaround for this issue.

The solution is to set the height of the iframe to a high value, such as 2000px. Then, the content won't jump back to the beginning if you scroll less than 2000 px from the top.